# How to capture date in next js head?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, head

I am trying to access Date.now() within a script tag inside a head section. I am using the following snippet of code:-

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";

export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <script
          // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
                  document.write("\x3Cscript src="https://somerandomeurl/initialize_pixel.js?v=' + Date.now() + '">\x3C/script>");`
          }}
        ></script>
      </Head>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I run this code I get the following output:-

');
Hello World. About

How can I get the date and avoid printing '); on the screen?

Comment: Why are you using a script to set the inner HTML of a script which document.writes another script? Just use the script you want at the end.

Comment: Hi, @Quentin I am given a pixel to be added on one of my landing pages. <script>document.write('<script src="https://someurli/initialize_pixel.js?v=' + Date.now() + '"\><\/script>');</script> I am using next js for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use template strings:

```
<Head>
   <script src={`https://somerandomeurl/initialize_pixel.js?v=${Date.now()}`}></script>
</Head>
```

Comment: Hi @PsyGik I am getting the following error :- Syntax error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text. Please check the following code https://codesandbox.io/s/integrating-whistle-pixel-81qej?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: yeah sorry about that, forgot the `{}` for `src`

Comment: Thank you @PsyGik for your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

import next/script instead of next/head.

```
import Script from 'next/script'
```

and use it

```
<Script src={`https://somerandomeurl/initialize_pixel.js?v=${Date.now()}`}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can try this

```
document.write(
      "<script src='https://somerandomeurl/initialize_pixel.js?v=" +
        Date.now() +
        "'></script>"
    );
```